# How can I set timeout in LB4?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback4

I am using LoopBack 4(LB4).
Access to the API disconnects in 120 seconds.
I want the timeout to be greater than 120 seconds.

I use LB4 with AWS Elastic Beanstalk Worker.
I want to change the timeout value for processing that takes more than 120 seconds.

Timeout value could be changed when using http-server-default-timeout option.
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/cli.html#cli_http_server_default_timeout_milliseconds

However, the above option can only be used on nodejs 12.x.

I want to know how to change server.timeout in Nodejs 10.x

Comment: Do you want to set the timeout in each controller method?

Comment: Even a specific controller is ok.

Is it possible to extend the timeout value beyond 120 seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
export class TestController {
    constructor(
        @inject(RestBindings.Http.RESPONSE) private response: Response
    ) {
        (this.response as any).setTimeout(1000);
    }
}
```

This works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I was saved!